# local variable persistence in memory (C++)

Tags: c++

I came across something this morning that's got me a bit baffled. When looking at some other issue I stumbled across what I thought was a bug, but having looked at it for a while I'm not sure it is. I am still confused by the behaviour though.

Take the code:

```
Class Coordinate
{
  double xyz[3];
  ...
}

void function()
{
  Coordinate localCoords = someOtherCoords;  //Copy constructor just copies values, no pointer assignment.

  //At this point the watch window lists the address of localCoords.xyz as e.g. 0x0012e7c4

  //More code, none of which should be modifying localCoords in any way ...

  //Now localCoords.xyz is at e.g. 0x00128cc0, and it's internal values have, unsurprisingly, changed.

  //More code, again not modifying localCoords.

  //localCoords.xyz is magically restored to its earlier address and contents.
  AnotherFunction(localCoords);  //Correct value(s) passed.
}
```

Now I understand the compiler (VC++ 6) is free to do as it wishes regards temp memory allocation, but when viewing the dissasembler the point at which the address changes isn't referencing localCoords or any of its members (it's comparing two bools, as it happens).

I'd assumed that given localCoords isn't nested in any way, and so is of function wide scope, that its structure would be persistent throughout the function, but that appears not to be the case.

This code has been working for years, and still works, so I guess this is really just a general question about what behaviour can be expected with this sort of thing, to maybe save me wasting time chasing non-existant bugs in the future.

Cheers for any input.

Comment: Are you attempting to debug code that has been optimized?  If so, then the source code does not match what is actually occurring.

Comment: Most so-called C++ compilers aren't fully standard conforming, but MSVC 6 is so old and broken that it really doesn't deserve to be called a C++ compiler. UPGRADE! Also, realize that our answers to your questions may not work with VC6, as what it accepts is too far away from standard C++.

Comment: It's a debug build, so shouldn't be optimised. Should it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: \*cough\* nolyc \*cough\*

Comment: VC6 is, to put it mildly, not a reliable source of any kind of information.

Comment: I understand the upgrade comment. This unfortunately is quite a sprawling legacy project and I don't think that's going to happen any time in the immediate future.

Comment: You need to show the code that you think does not modify `localCoords`. It may be being modified and you may be missing it.

Comment: There's a lot of code. Or at least there would be if all the function calls were expanded upon. I'm as sure as you can reasonably be that it isn't getting modified. Besides, what would be buggy enough to modify the internal xyz address (it's defined as an array, not a pointer), fill it with rubbish, then modify it back again? Plus I stepped through the ASM and the point at which it changed was local to function() and should not have had any bearing on it. I'll just put it down to compiler weirdness.